# Having trouble with customized cell UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to add a customCell which simply will allow me to left align one string, and right align the other. In a previous question someone had suggested the following, but I am having problems getting it to work with my code. Xcode says: RootviewController may not respond to --contentView, and that call [[self contentView] addSubView:item] or [[self contentView] addSubView:rank] will crash my app at runtime

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

            UILabel *rank = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 20];
            //Mess around with the rects, I am just merely guessing.
            [rank setTag:5];
            [[self contentView] addSubView:rank];
            [rank release];


            UILabel *item = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 5, 220, 20];
            //Important
            [item setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
            [item setTag:6];
            [[self contentView] addSubView:item];
            [item release];
        }

        UILabel *rank = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
        UILabel *item = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:6];

        rank = @"leftside";
        item = @"rightside";

    }
```

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looking at

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:item];
[cell.contentView addSubview:rank];

rank.text = @"leftside";
item.text = @"rightside";
```

**One more thing to note here.** If your UITableView is `scrollEnabled`, you will have problems with `cellReusability` and your labels will get messed up with subsequent scrolls. I would suggest that you subclass UITableViewCells and add those in the layout, and then use the  `CustomUITableViewCells`.

Comment: Thanks this was the issue, however as you pointed out scrolling up/down seems to break everything. Any examples of what you describe with CustomUITableViewCells?

Answer (score 1):

`self` here is the controller. Instead of making `self` the receiver, you should be sending `contentView` to the cell you just created.